# jQuery(element).css("right") returns auto, that results to NaN in chrome only

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

To be precise on creating a slider, I got stuck in a situation (though I completed my task with some other trick) on which I would like to gather some more information.

So, I was calculating value from right, of the inner div which is actually getting scrolled. So that when it ends, I will scroll back again.

The value I was confused about, is:

```
jQuery(element).css("right").toString();
```

It returns "**auto**" in chrome while a value like-**1200** in firefox. Does it have to do with any limitation in chrome? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I tested on firefox and chrome and in both I get the same result: "auto". I don't know your markup or anything but I don't see the difference you notice with this browsers. (Firefox 37.0.1 y Chrome 50.0.2661)

Anyway if you want to know in pixels the right of an element you can do it with position and width.

```
(jQuery(element).position().left + jQuery(element).width()).toString();
```

Of course this only gives you the right **position** of the element. I hope that's is what you need.

---

In order to seek what's is happened in chrome or firefox so they throw a diferent response on `jQuery(element).css("right")` I update my firefox (46.0.1) so now chrome and firefox are update.

I made a simple & stupid [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jbat5us/) so we can see the differences together with a common source.

When I run this jsFiddle in chrome or firefox I get the same result: "**auto**".
Please check if you are getting the same result as I.
Maybe the problem is on how chrome and firefox are dealing with the markup and that explain the behaviour.
Coul you please provide a jsFiddler or similar where this problems happen?

Comment: As I said, I have already done it with some other trick, like taking left position. Though was unsure of why chrome is giving different result. Anyways thanks for your answer

Comment: Sorry, I really think that the problem is with how obtain that "right" position and don't of how the browsers behave different. I edit the answer trying to solve that question too

Comment: I think there might be some other cause which is causing this issue. My files are distributed where I was getting this issue, so creating same scenario in jsfiddle would be complex. Moreover, in normal fiddle or single file scenarios, even I never faced this thing. Thanks for giving it time.

Comment: You're welcome! I don't give up so easily, there's a live site when I can check what's going on or maybe you could post the markup that you are getting trouble with? I really think that is a problem either the markup or the styles involved.

Comment: I appreciate your concern and enthusiasm, though I have already made many changes in my plugin now, and it is much difficult to replicate same thing again, at my end too. 

There was a scenario when I got stuck and unable to find any explanation to that, so I tried to get some learning from here. Though at that time only I fulfilled my work using some other trick,